# JPA sequence generation strategy IDENTITY for AS400 table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, ibm-midrange

I have mentioned a sequence generation strategy as IDENTITY on my entity class for the primary key of a table in AS400 system.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "SEQNO")
private Integer seqNo;
```

The table's primary key column is defined as GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY in database.
    `SEQNO BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1)`
My understanding of IDENTITY strategy is that it will leave the primary key generation responsibility to the table itself.
The problem that I am facing is that somehow in one environment, while inserting record in the table it gives me `[SQL0803] Duplicate Key value specified.`
Now there are couple of questions in my mind:

1. Is my understanding correct for `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)`?
2. In which scenario table will generate Duplicate key?
3. I figured out there are sequence values missing in the table, i.e. after 4, the sequence till 20 is missing and I do not know if someone manually deleted it or not, but could this be related to duplicate key generation?

Answer (score 0):

1. YES. `IDENTITY` means use in-datastore features like "AUTO_INCREMENT", "SERIAL", "IDENTITY". So any `INSERT` should **omit** the `IDENTITY` column, and will pull the value back (into memory, for that object) after the `INSERT` is executed.
2. Should never get a duplicate key. Check the `INSERT` statement being used.
3. Some external process using the same table? Use the logs to see SQL and work it out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use JPA, but what you have seems reasonable to me.

As far as the DB2 for i side...

Are you sure you're getting the duplicate key error on the identity column?  Are there no other columns defined as unique?

**It is possible to have a duplicate key error on an identity column.**

What you need to realize is that the next identity value is stored in the table object; not calculated on the fly.  When I started using Identities, I got bit by a CMS package that routinely used CPYF to move data between newly created versions of a table.  The new version of the table would have a next identity value of 1, even though there might be 100K records in it.  (the package has since gotten smarter :)  But the point remains that CPYF for instance, doesn't play nice with identity columns.

Additionally, it is possible to override the `GENERATED ALWAYS` via the `OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE` or `OVERRIDING USER VALUE` clauses of the `INSERT` statement.  But inserting with an override has no effect on the stored next identity value.  I suppose one could consider CPYF as using `OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE`

Now, as far as your missing identities...

1. Data was deleted
2. Data was copied in with overridden identities
3. Somebody `ALTER TABLE <...> ALTER COLUMN <...> RESTART WITH`
4. You lost the use of some values

Let me explain #4.  For performance reasons, DB2 for i by default will cache 20 identity values for a process to use.  So if you have two processes adding records, one will get values 1-20 the other 20-40.  This allows both process to insert concurrently.  However, if process 1 only inserts 10 records, then identity values 11-20 will be lost.  If you absolutely must have continuous identity values, then specify `NO CACHE` during the creation of the identity.

```
create table test
 myid int generated always 
    as identity 
    (start with 1, increment by 1, no cache)
```

Finally, with respect to the caching of identity values.  While confirming a few things for this answer, I noticed that the use of `ALTER TABLE` to add a new column seemed to cause a loss of the cached values.  I inserted 3 rows, did the alter table and the next row got an identity value of 21.